# How do I format a paystub correctly in Java with this code?

Tags: java

I've been having issues with this coding assignment using Java for displaying a paystub for a variety of inputs. The code (as shown below) uses the scanner input function as a method for these 'employees' to input their information, and have a paystub printed out back to them. Currently this is the code I have:

```
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Gross Pay:     " + "$");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", grossPay);
        System.out.print("\nRetirement:    " + "$"); 
        System.out.printf(" %.2f", retirementFund);
        System.out.print("\nTax:           " + "$");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", tax);
        System.out.print("\n------------------------");
        System.out.print("\nNet Pay:       " + "$");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", netPay);
        System.out.print("\n==========================================");
```

The issue I'm having specifically is that based on this coding, I have an issue with this case output:

```
------------------------------------------
Gross Pay:     $7160.40
Retirement:    $ 372.34
Tax:           $1900.66
------------------------
Net Pay:       $4887.40
==========================================
```

being correct, but this case:

```
------------------------------------------
Gross Pay:     $0.00
Retirement:    $ 0.00
Tax:           $0.00
------------------------
Net Pay:       $0.00
==========================================
```

is wrong, it should be:

```
------------------------------------------
Gross Pay:     $   0.00
Retirement:    $   0.00
Tax:           $   0.00
------------------------
Net Pay:       $   0.00
==========================================
```

I implemented the coded in space for the retirement as it got the most correct results in mimir classroom, but this case is wrong.
How do I code the print functions to format the display to be

```
Gross Pay:      $####.##
Retirement:     $####.##
Tax:            $####.##
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

For your printf() function, you need to specify both the width of the number as well as its precision. So your flag needs to be "%7.2f" to print the number with 6 digits and a decimal point. This number will be right justified with leading spaces.

Comment: You are such a wonderful person :) this worked perfectly. I didn't know about the width being decided but figured there was something like it! 60/90 to 90/90!